# Force TypeORM to Check all columns using the decorators - NestJS

Tags: node.js, typescript, validation, nestjs, typeorm

Is there a way to force the uniqueness validator in the TypeORM entity to check all the columns and then return a message for all the errors it finds?

for example, this schema:

```
import {
  BaseEntity,
  Column,
  Entity,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  Unique,
} from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
@Unique('UQ_USERNAME', ['username'])
@Unique('UQ_EMAIL', ['email'])
export class UserModel extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;
  @Column()
  username: string;
  @Column()
  pwd: string;
  @Column()
  email: string;
}
```

if the email and username are not unique, it will check the username first, then return an error for the username only. It will not continue to check the email.

I need to know all the errors in the columns to handle them all in the frontend, not every error separately.

Note: I don't want to check every column of them with the code using (.find) method if there is a way to get this result by typeorm decorators directly it will be better than do a multiple request from databases for the same functionality of the (@Unique) decorator

Comment: I believe that that's how the database in general works. Postgres gives errors in that format, it won't tell you all of the errors, just the first constraint that failed, so it may not be doable unless you pre-search the database for those values

Comment: so there is no way to workaround this issue with the typeorm library decorators?

Comment: How would they? All those decorators _should_ be doing is translating a Typescript syntax to a proper SQL syntax when it comes to creating the database table. It's then up to how the database to respond about the errors when it comes to uniqueness

Comment: Which is more efficient, using a query search or using the (@Unique) decorator for this issue? which one will have the higher cost?

Comment: Do you _want_ to allow for duplicate values in the case of a search not finding anything for whatever reason?

Comment: I mean, if I let the username and email pass without adding "@unique" to the entity, and then in the code I do a query search for them, will this be more expensive than using "@Unique" in the entity?

Comment: Instead of using "@Unique" decorator, use query search to validate the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most databases will respond with the first constraint failed, not all of the issues with a data modification query, as a way to keep load lighter on the server (if it's gonna fail anyways, why keep going?). So the only way to know if you'll violate multiple constrains (like unique username and unique email) is to query for both and then parse the results yourself.

In the comments, you asked if it's more cost efficient to use a query to search for this or to keep it to the `UNIQUE` constraint. If you go with the query approach and don't have the `UNIQUE` constraint on the table, you're opening yourself up to eventually allow for duplicates, either from the possibility of multiple requests at the same time that cause the searches to come back with no results, but allow for the inserts to happen, or direct modification of the database.

Keep with the use of `UNIQUE` in the table definition, and handle how the database returns the errors. It will almost undoubtedly be a better approach.